ArcGIS Pro - empty container when adding DWG or DXF file
I am struggling with adding the DWG file to my ArcGIS Pro project.
By following this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I8sbUMDbYVI
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dZE9USM6FH8
I am struggling with errors, which I can't combat at this moment.
I am new to ArcGIS Pro and I would like to get started with the project I am working on.
I've used the Map -> Add data option and added my DWG file.
However, the drawing appears near the coordinates 0,0 on my map.
I tried to change the map CRS from WGS 84 to OSGB 36 but in vain. The Define projection tool doesn't work either as I get the error like this:

Is there any smart way of loading DWG file into ArcGIS Pro (preferably in the OSGB36 crs system)?

Do you have access to an ETL tool?  Error 000229 is too generic https://support.esri.com/en-us/knowledge-base/000229-cannot-open-value-1462482943350-000012177#:~:text=When%20running%20a%20geoprocessing%20tool,tool%20is%20unavailable%20or%20invalid.
